# How to pass attributes from amazon connect to amazon lambda?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I try to pass an attribute from AWS connect to lambda, but it keeps saying in lambda that the key I called did not being defined.
Can someone point out what did I do wrong?

Here is the error message from connect log, lambda log and lambda code
Connect log

```
{
    "Results": "The Lambda Function Returned An Error.",
    "ContactId": "224feaf0-406e-46c4-b2ba-f606c58597f8",
    "ContactFlowId": "arn:aws:connect:ap-southeast- 
    2:517244054371:instance/0eedbbca-8550-4d6a-a964-0ae08655590c/contact- 
    flow/8d9cbdd2-fc1f-4cde-9997-0781e00676e6",
    "ContactFlowModuleType": "InvokeExternalResource",
    "Timestamp": "2019-03-18T22:33:28.482Z",
    "Parameters": {
        "FunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-2:517244054371:function:dbtrigger",
        "Parameters": {
            "telNumber": "1111"
        },
        "TimeLimit": "3000"
    }
}
```

lambda log

> [ERROR] KeyError: 'Parameters' Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 10, in lambda_handler
>       'ticketNum': event["Details"]["Parameters"]["Parameters"]["telNumber"],

lambda code

```
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    table = dynamodb.Table('Dynamo_Ticket')

    response = table.get_item(
        Key={
            'ticketNum': event["Details"]["Parameters"]["Parameters"]["telNumber"]

        }
    )

    item = response['Item']
    name = item['firstName']

    print(item)
    print("Hello, {}" .format(name))
    return name
```

Comment: just print `event["Details"]["Parameters"]["Parameters"]["telNumber"]` before **table.getitem**

Comment: Sorry, I did not get your point. Could you kindly write the code?